# Sequential function mapping in python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a bunch of functions in a list:

```
funcs = [f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]
```

and all of the functions take in return a single argument, eg.

```
f1 = lambda x: x*2
```

I'd like to map all these functions together

```
result = lambda x: f5(f4(f3(f2(f1(x)))))
```

or, iterating over `funcs`

```
def dispatch(x):
    for f in funcs:
        x = f(x)
    return x
```

`dispatch` works fine, but I couldn't figure out a clean way to do this using `iterools`. Is it possible? Does this sequential function mapping idiom have a name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point in using `itertools` here; you are producing **one** output, and you could not apply this to an infinite iterable. You have to have a *finite* number of functions in the input iterable for this to work at all.

Use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

x = reduce(lambda res, func: func(res), funcs, x)
```

The [`functools.reduce()` import](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) helps the above work in both Python 2 and 3.

`reduce()`, together with `map()`, `filter()` and, yes, `itertools`, is an often used tool in [*functional programming*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html).

Answer (score 2):

Another (less efficient, alas) way of looking at Martijn's answer is to realize that you want to compose the list of functions.

```
# function composition: compose(f,g)(x) = f(g(x))
def compose(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

# Identity for function composition
# compose(f, identity)(x) = f(x)
identity = lambda x: x

# result(x) = f1(f2(...fn(x)...))
result = reduce(compose, funcs, identity)
```