# multiple logarithm in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want take logarithm multiple times. We know this

```
import numpy as np
np.log(x)
```

now the second logarithm would be

```
np.log(np.log(x))
```

what if one wants to take n number of logs? surely it would not be pythonic to repeat n times as above.

Comment: define a recursive function to do that

Comment: @Eliethesaiyan An iterative loop would be better in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repeat a function n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359828/how-to-repeat-a-function-n-times)

Comment: I hope you're aware that even the biggest 64-bit float goes to a negative number in just 5 applications of `numpy.log`.

Comment: @user2357112 just need to make sure `x` is complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @eugenhu's suggestion, one way is to use a generic function which loops iteratively:

```
import numpy as np

def repeater(f, n):
    def fn(i):
        result = i
        for _ in range(n):
            result = f(result)
        return result
    return fn

repeater(np.log, 5)(x)
```

Comment: Neat. Can be used to decorate your own functions with a small modification.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following little trick:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> 
>>> k = 4
>>> x = 1e12
>>> 
>>> y = np.array(x)
>>> reduce(np.log, (k+1) * (y,))[()]
0.1820258315495139
```

and back:

```
>>> reduce(np.exp, (k+1) * (y,))[()]
999999999999.9813
```

On my machine this is slightly faster than @jp_data_analysis' approach:

```
>>> def f_pp(ufunc, x, k):
...     y = np.array(x)
...     return reduce(ufunc, (k+1) * (y,))[()]
... 
>>> x = 1e12
>>> k = 5
>>> 
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100000)
>>> 
>>> repeat('repeater(np.log, 5)(x)', **kwds)
[0.5353733809897676, 0.5327484680456109, 0.5363518510130234]
>>> repeat('f_pp(np.log, x, 5)', **kwds)
[0.4512511100037955, 0.4380568229826167, 0.45331112697022036]
```

To be fair, their approach is more flexible. Mine uses quite specific properties of unary `ufunc`s and numpy `array`s.

Larger `k` is also possible. For that we need to make sure that `x` is complex because `np.log` will not switch automatically.

```
>>> x = 1e12+0j
>>> k = 50
>>> 
>>> f_pp(np.log, x, 50)
(0.3181323483680859+1.3372351153002153j)
>>> f_pp(np.exp, _, 50)
(1000000007040.9696+6522.577629950761j)
# not that bad, all things considered ...
>>>
>>> repeat('f_pp(np.log, x, 50)', **kwds)
[4.272890724008903, 4.266964592039585, 4.270542044949252]
>>> repeat('repeater(np.log, 50)(x)', **kwds)
[5.799160094989929, 5.796761817007791, 5.80835147597827]
```

Answer (score 1):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398472/sequential-function-mapping-in-python), you can compose functions:

**Code**

```
import itertools as it
import functools as ft

import numpy as np


def compose(f, g): 
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

identity = lambda x: x
```

**Demo**

```
ft.reduce(compose, it.repeat(np.log, times=2), identity)(10)
# 0.83403244524795594

ft.reduce(compose, it.repeat(np.log, times=3), identity)(10)
# -0.18148297420509205
```